# uppercase Letter count, lowercase letter count, blank count, and lower to upper conversion- C

Tags: c, counter, uppercase, lowercase

I'm somewhat new to the language (C), but what i am trying to do is pretty simple imo. i'm sure im just neglecting something or running into some logical errors.

As the title suggests, all i want my program to do is count the # of lowercase letters, uppercase letters, and blank spaces. As an additional function, it also converts the lowercase letters entered into uppercase.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){

    int iochar, numdigits=0, numlower=0, numupper=0, numwhites=0;

    printf("Please enter a phrase:\n\n");

    while((iochar=getchar())!=EOF) {
        if ((iochar=' ')||(iochar='\t')||(iochar='\n')){
            numwhites++;
            putchar(iochar);
        }
        else if((iochar>='0')&&(iochar<='9')) {
         numdigits++;
         putchar(iochar);
        }
        else if(('a'<=iochar)&&(iochar<='z')) {
            numlower++;
            putchar(iochar-32);
        } 
        else if(('A'<=iochar)&&(iochar<='Z')) {
            numupper++;
            putchar(iochar);
        }
        else 
           putchar(iochar); 
    }

    printf("%d white characters, %d digits, ",numwhites,numdigits);
    printf("%d lowercase have been converted to ",numlower);
    printf("uppercase and %d uppercase.\n",numupper);

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Good. And what is the question?

Comment: if you miss to differentiate between = and == , while coding, keep the constant on left while comparing. e.g.  if (' ' == iochar) . you can avoid doing mistake this way.

Comment: @yadab: and how do you avoid mistakes when both sides of the comparison are lvalues?

Comment: @SteveJessop : I do not know! But this for comparing constants with lvalues.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if ((iochar=' ')||(iochar='\t')||(iochar='\n'))
```

in this you assign to iochar and will always be true. It should be a comparison:

```
if ((iochar==' ')||(iochar=='\t')||(iochar=='\n'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Please look into `isupper(int c)`, `islower(int c)`, and `isspace(int c)` which are defined in `ctype.h`. You could perhaps also benefit from `toupper(int c)` and `tolower(int c)` which are defined in the same file.

Also note Sani's answer, comparison in C is `==` while assignment is `=`. Additionally, it *is* possible to assign within `if` statements, which make possible and even common errors such as yours. In my opinion, a good convention is to write comparisons like this:

```
if ('\n' == iochar)
```

This way, if I were to make a typo and write this instead:

```
if ('\n' = iochar)
```

I would get a syntax error during compilation and not weird behavior during runtime.

Comment: An alternative is to use a compiler that warns about `if (iochar = '\n')` and then write whichever way you find clearer. The risk is spurious warnings, especially in code that you didn't write and don't want to modify to suppress the warnings.

Comment: @Steve: What `gcc` does in this case is ask you to wrap the assignment in parens to suppress the warning. So you write `if ((iochar = '\n'))` if you really do want assignment. A common idiom uses this style of assignment in `if`s for `malloc(2)`: `if (!(p = malloc(sizeof(*p)))) { ... }`.

Comment: indeed, and that's why if someone has written `if (c = *str++)` you might not want to have to change their code to `if ((c = *str++))` in order to suppress the warning. But in new code it all works fine.

Comment: Thank you for your input although it has raised another question! please help me out on my second question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9017744/using-a-different-library-in-c

Answer (score 0):

I think Sani Huttenen has solved your question pretty well. I'd also recommend you to call

```
putchar(iochar)
```

just once at the end of your bucle... It would be clearer.