# Using a different library in C

Tags: c, function

I just coded from scratch a program that would count the upper and lowercase letters and blank spaces of whatever the user input. Since then I found out that code for those specific functions have already been prewritten in another library! My question is, how can all the code that I have written below be simplified with the use of

`isupper(int c)`, `islower(int c)`, and `isspace(int c)` which are defined in `ctype.h`.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void){
int iochar, numdigits=0, numlower=0, numupper=0, numwhites=0;

printf("Please enter a phrase:\n\n");

while((iochar=getchar())!=EOF) 
{
    if ((iochar==' ')||(iochar=='\t')||(iochar=='\n'))
    {
        numwhites++;
        putchar(iochar);
    }
    else 
        if((iochar>='0')&&(iochar<='9')) 
        {
            numdigits++;
            putchar(iochar);
        }
        else 
            if(('a'<=iochar)&&(iochar<='z')) 
            {
                numlower++;
                putchar(iochar-32);
            } 
            else 
                if(('A'<=iochar)&&(iochar<='Z'))
                {
                    numupper++;
                    putchar(iochar);
                }
                else 
                    putchar(iochar);    
}

printf("%d white characters, %d digits, ",numwhites,numdigits);
printf("%d lowercase have been converted to ",numlower);
printf("uppercase and %d uppercase.\n",numupper);

printf("\n\n");


return 0;}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is it written better and cleaned up:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
    int iochar, numdigits=0, numlower=0, numupper=0, numwhites=0;

    printf("Please enter a phrase:\n\n");

    while ((iochar=getchar()) != EOF) {
        // increase counts where necessary
        if (isspace(iochar)) {
            numwhites++;
        } else if (isdigit(iochar)) {
            numdigits++;
        } else if (islower(iochar)) {
            numlower++;
            iochar = toupper(iochar);
        } else if (isupper(iochar)) {
            numupper++;
        }

        // this happens always, don't put it in the if's
        putchar(iochar);
    }

    printf("%d white characters, %d digits, ", numwhites, numdigits);
    printf("%d lowercase have been converted to ", numlower);
    printf("uppercase and %d uppercase.\n", numupper);

    printf("\n\n");

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: excellent. It looks a lot cleaner now. thank you! Where can i go to actually read the code for the isupper() and other functions?

Comment: Almost. When the character is lower case then it should be converted to upper case when printing it out.

Comment: @Sani Huttunen: ah totally skipped over that. Let me fix that.

Comment: @user1145538: Well, that's a bit of a painful point, since that strongly depends on your compiler.

Comment: @nightcracker: would it help if i told you i'm on a mac and i use the gcc compiler?

Comment: @user1145538: Here is the [source code for ctype.h](http://www-zeuthen.desy.de/apewww/APE/software/nlibc/html/ctype_8h-source.html) from nlibc, which is nice and clean. It would be pretty much the same for other implementations, too.

Comment: @user1145538: Yes that would, you can look at the GCC libc git tree for the files [ctype.h](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=ctype/ctype.h;h=4e3f1676113bd8b2956604d250f2f34bfabacc39;hb=HEAD) and [ctype.c](http://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=ctype/ctype.c;h=1b606c5b2d7f265e578c6db83aaa682e7380b303;hb=HEAD). Keep in mind that the standard library code is often heavily optimized and not very readable. nlibc is a better alternative in terms of readility and understandability, as cha0site suggested.

Comment: @user1145538: Oh, but note that larger implementations do things like handling locale, so that characters like Ä also count as uppercase.

Comment: wow, you guys are amazing, thank you very much. I'm really loving the Stack Overflow community! Goodnight from CA (4:20am) !

Comment: @user1145538: Also, consider registering a real account on Stack Overflow. And if my answer solved your problem consider marking it as such by clicking green tick to the left of my answer.

Comment: ctype.h "functions" are normally not functions at all but implemented as macros in the header file.  To see your compiler's specific implementation, open the header file itself.  For library functions in general they are provided as object code not source.  Whether you have access to the source depends on the license terms for the specific library.

Answer (score 1):

Just `#include <ctype.h>` and then change e.g.

```
if((iochar==' ')||(iochar=='\t')||(iochar=='\n'))
```

to

```
if (isspace(iochar))
```

etc.

For full details see [man ctype](http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/ctype/).